# Create "no more scroll possible" effect for HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, effect, horizontalscrollview

An android WebView and some other views have a nice animation effect of "no more scroll possible" - nice blue filled arc animating with the direction of your finger if you try to scroll after the max scrolling reached. The arc animates as you move the finger and smoothly disappears when you remove/stop the finger. In order to see it, just go to device Settings and try to scroll beyond the maximum.

I'd like to implement the same effect for my HorizontalScrollView.

Please pay attention, it is NOT about fading edge (AFAIK).

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: can't you use listview, they have attributes for that?, with horizontal scroll view you will have to do that manually

Comment: I need to check how much effort will it take to switch to listview. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HorizontalScrollview should behave like this by default. But what you can try is adding this to your HorizontalScrollview in XML:

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

or add this to your code:

```
yourHorizontalScrollview.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
```

So it will always show the animation left or right depending on the direction you scroll.

Comment: Well, this is not what I get. Will create an empty project with a single horizontalscrollview to check it out. Thanks